# How do I start from a different location in Android Studio with Mapbox?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

The Mapbox API allows integration of map services into Android Studio applications.
I'm using it to create a new navigation application. It doesn't follow the device's location but always starts in San Francisco this is ok for my purposes. However, I can't figure out where to change the starting location.

Link to the Code I'm using:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android-examples/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/navigation/examples/turnbyturn/TurnByTurnExperienceActivity.kt

I think it should be changeable here somewhere.
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: I guess you are talking about emulator location?

Comment: Hello, yes it emulates a location but I don't know if it's the location from the device that is taken or just a hard programmed-in location. Do you think it should change if I change the location of the emulated device? I will try that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own Answer, it is changeable within the function:
onStartNavigation()

Answer (score 1):

You can use mock location in emulator.

1. Open emulator.
2. Download any mock location app from play store in emulator (you can also side-load apk by drag and dropping apk in emulator).
3. In phone settings, go to mock location (System-> Developer Options -> Select mock location app) and select that mock location app you installed.
4. Select your desired location from mock location app.

some mock location apps on play store -:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps

Comment: Hello, do you really need an app for this? Can't I just use the emulator settings to change locations? Asking because it didn't work with setting the emulator to a different location. But I can also try with an app.

Comment: you can upload kml file to emulator setting (not emulator's internal settings) from 3 menu dots on side of emulator. to create kml file follow -> https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-google-maps-create-kml-file-49545.html. But not sure whether it will pin point exact location or not.

Comment: Hello, thanks for all your answers. However, I noticed that the app doesn't use the emulator/device position. (Which is fine for me, I just need it for simulator purposes). So it has to be settable in the code somewhere. But thank you anyways!